# How does .'{} ohm{}'.format(total, 's' * (total > 1)) in the function?

Tags: python

I've been doing Python challenges to learn the language. One of them is as follows:

> Create a function that takes an array of values resistance that are
> connected in series, and calculates the total resistance of the
> circuit in ohms
>
> Note:
>
> - All inputs will be valid.
> - singular ohm for values <= 1. (e.g 15 ohms, 0.8 ohm)

My solution to the problem was:

```
def series_resistance(lst):
    if sum(lst) > 1:
        return str(sum(lst)) + " ohms"
    else:
        return str(sum(lst)) + " ohm"
```

Looking at how other people solved it, I found:

```
def series_resistance(lst):
    total = sum(lst)
    return '{} ohm{}'.format(total, 's' * (total > 1))
```

How does their version of the function work?

Comment: What part isnt clear?

Comment: You put only the formatting thing in the title, so  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format This uses a trick that True==1 and False==0, so 's'*False == '' (no s added) and 's'*True == 's'

Comment: to get this right, The first {} is for the total and the second is for the s, where s is put if the condition >1 is true, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how does `format` work in the provided example, `'{} ohm{}'.format(total, 's' * (total > 1))`, then Python is replacing `{}` in the string with values provided as arguments to the format function.

In this example, `total` as the first and `'s'` or `''` as the second, depending on the value of `total` (when operating on strings, `'string' * True == 'string'` and `'string' * False == ''`).

From Python 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) to achieve same result:

```
def series_resistance(lst):
    total = sum(lst)
    return f"{total} ohm{'s'*(total > 1)}"
```